# .NET Core no message whatsoever on unhandled exception

Tags: .net-5, unhandled-exception

Trying to migrate app from .NET Framework to .NET (Core) 5.0, my task is made harder by the fact that whenever there's an unhandled exception in the .NET 5 app, I get no error message, no "Application error" event log, no nothing: The app just stops.

This contrasts the .NET Framework 4.8 app I tried on the same machine, which outputs the unhandled exception and adds an "Application Error" entry to the event log.

Is that normal, or is my .NET 5 installation broken somehow?

Comment: you need to provide more info like , if this is console app or webapi or any other kind of project. and did you already tried handling the exception by putting try catch

Comment: @Nitz You're right, I tried reproducing the lack of exception dump in a "regular" console app that only contains the `throw` statement, and all three of them (4.8, 5.0, 6.0) show the exception dump. I'll test more but I suspect it's linked to webapi projects indeed.

Comment: for ASP.Net core webapi you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72740931/asp-net-core-how-to-do-something-before-shutdown-on-fatal-error/72742387#72742387

Comment: ...On further testing I on longer reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are Exception Handler Events on ApplicationDomain that you can try;

- **[AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=net-5.0) += UnhandledHandler**
- **[AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception?view=net-5.0) += FirstChanceHandler**

Debug with this Events to observe errors, you should define at the beggining of the "Main" method in Program.cs

Comment: But I didn't have to do this in .Net 4.8... In fact I remember there was a bug like this in *early versions* of .Net 4, which also failed to show info when a program crashed with unhandled exception.

Comment: I don't know the reason but I know I got same issue at past, but in .Net Core there is no way to handle Application Exception instead of this events(I am not talking about Middlewares which are for the requests not Application Itself). You can try throw an exception in Main Method that middleware won't be handle any issue because they weren't initiated yet.