# ASP.NET Core how to do something before shutdown/on fatal error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET server. I would like to log fatal error, that crashes server. And save in database some information about this fatal error. What should I use? I thought about `IHostApplicationLifetime`, but it's used for graceful shutdown and not for fatal errors.

Comment: Naive approach: wrap `.Run` in a try/catch?

Comment: okay, that was stupid... Programed too much, thanks :D I didn't think about something that obvious @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: A run time exception that kills the process without giving you an opportunity to run recovery operation is called fatal - for the very same reason. It takes execution into the realms where recovery is simply impossible. In short, you dont stand chance of doing anything.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar Logging != recovery though. You could certainly log anything except a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: You can try server logs of web-server under which your application is running. Most of the times, your application is running under the context of IIS (or similar web server). Server should get a notification about why its process was killed or why OS thinks the process should be terminated, which then typically gets written to the logs.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar : I responded with previous messages a few seconds after your comment. Yes, I would look at the logs, although I doubt executing application will have any opportunity to write info into the log. Most likely it will be the parent process or the OS itself, like application server events. etc.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar Sure. It definitely depends on the situation though. In my own situation, logging in such a scenario would be entirely possible as we host directly with  built-in Kestrel (though behind a reverse proxy), and any errors logged to the console are ingested by Google's logging mechanisms. But I agree that in the case of something like IIS it might be easier to look for existing logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use serilog you could do something like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore",LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}", theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate)
                .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(),"\logs\serilog.json", shared: true)
               .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting up");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseSerilog();
            });
    }
```